# Need explanation on ternary operator of select2 code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

In select2 component of jquery I've encountered the following code in 'keypress' event listener.

```
 a.isOpen() ? c === d.ESC || c === d.TAB || c === d.UP && b.altKey ? (a.close(),
                b.preventDefault()) : c === d.ENTER ? (a.trigger("results:select", {}),
                b.preventDefault()) : c === d.SPACE && b.ctrlKey ? (a.trigger("results:toggle", {}),
                b.preventDefault()) : c === d.UP ? (a.trigger("results:previous", {}),
                b.preventDefault()) : c === d.DOWN && (a.trigger("results:next", {}),
                b.preventDefault()) : (c === d.ENTER || c === d.SPACE || c === d.DOWN && b.altKey) && (a.open(),
                b.preventDefault())
```

Can someone please explain this complex structure?

Answer (score 1):

Ternaries translate into if and else statements and you can nest them inside of each other.

it translate roughly into this. You can keep going down the rabbit hole breaking it into more nested if and else statements

```
if(a.isOpen()){

    if(c === d.ESC || c === d.TAB || c === d.UP && b.altKey){
        a.close();
        b.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        if(d.ENTER){
            a.trigger("results:select", {};
            b.preventDefault();
        }
        else{

            if(d.SPACE && b.ctrlKey){
                a.trigger("results:toggle", {});
                b.preventDefault();
            }
            else{

                if(c === d.UP){
                    a.trigger("results:previous", {});
                    b.preventDefault()
                }
                else{
                    ...and so on and so on
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```